# what will happen if we directly call run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class "TestRunnable" which overrides run method by implementing `Runnable`.
Running overridden run method, as follow :

```
TestRunnable nr = new TestRunnable();
Thread t = new Thread(nr);
t.setName("Fred");
t.start();
```

- What if i directly call `t.run();`
- What happen if we don't call `t.start();` ?

Comment: why not give it a shot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `run` method is just another method.  If you call it directly, then it will execute not in another thread, but in the current thread.

Here's my test `TestRunnable`:

```
class TestRunnable implements Runnable
{
   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println("TestRunnable in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
}
```

Output if only `start` is called:

```
TestRunnable in Fred
```

Output if only `run` is called:

```
TestRunnable in main
```

If `start` isn't called, then the `Thread` created will never run.  The main thread will finish and the `Thread` will be garbage collected.

Output if neither is called:  (nothing)

Comment: Looks like you've covered it now, will delete my very similar answer.

Comment: Start creates separate call stack for new thread and then run() is called by JVM

Answer (score 1):

If you call start method then a separate thread will be allocated to execute the run method, means you achieve multi threading . But  when you call run method directly then it becomes a normal method and main method itself will execute the run method , means no multi threading.

Answer (score 0):

If `run()` method is called directly instead of `start()` method in Java code, `run()` method will be treated as a normal overridden method of the thread class (or runnable interface). This run method will be executed within the context of the current thread, not in a new thread.

**Example**

Let’s create a class and spawn two threads and cause some delay in the execution if they are real threads then there will be context switching – while one thread is not executing another thread will execute. When the start method is not called no new threads are created thus there won’t be any context switching and the execution will be sequential.

```
public class MyThreadClass extends Thread{
  @Override
  public void run(){
    System.out.println("In run method " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
      System.out.println("i - " + i);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThreadClass mc1 = new MyThreadClass(“MyThread1”);
    MyThreadClass mc2 = new MyThreadClass();
    mc1.run();
    mc2.run();
  }
}
```